# Does Wolfenstein: Youngblood on Xbox have mouse and keyboard support?

Tags: xbox-one, wolfenstein-young-blood

I can't seem to find anything about mouse and keyboard support on the  official store page:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/wolfenstein-youngblood/c421zx7rcg0w?activetab=pivot:regionofsystemrequirementstab

Has anyone with the game tested this?